# Unable to access data from external list by REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, bcs, external-list

I'm trying to retrieve items from external list by REST API. The external list displays data from SQL Server view. Unfortunately I always get error saying that the list does not exist. This happens both in the case of using api by GUID (like _api/web/lists(guid'96A46528-61AC-4130-8533-67978DAC8A14')) or by title. I've also retrieved all the lists (_api/web/lists) and there's no list by that ID or title. What could be the reason?
Can Sharepoint version (this is Standard, not Enterprise) have something to do with it?

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="pl-PL">Lista nie istnieje. Wybrana strona zawiera nieistniejącą listę. Mogła zostać usunięta przez innego użytkownika.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Comment: Are you using the correct URL for your site? E.g. is it a subsite and if so are you referencing that site's URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available to access Exeternal List Item using SharePoint Rest API:

[Manipulating SharePoint External Lists using REST](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2017/07/manipulating-sharepoint-external-lists-using-rest/)

Check out the site url and make sure the site url used in Rest API is the one which external list.